# After Java Upgrade 8.0.6.15 to 8.0.6.25 handshake_failure, but works after replace old security folder from 8.0.6.15 to new java version 8.0.6.25

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2, sslhandshakeexception, tls1.3

I have an issue when I upgrade Java from 8.0.6.15 to 8.0.6.25 after this is done, and I do a test connection to an endpoint that I will call "endpoint.server" I get a handshake_failure.

Beside the upgrade I haven't changed anything, so the Security policy files etc are still the same.
When I check the logs I do see something strange and that is the following, during the ClientHello handshake message stage:

```
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "43 8B 8E 7E 3E 91 E9 9D 4A 1B 60 40 9B 42 AD ED 18 14 48 06 3E 84 4D A3 C4 F8 ED 8D DE 73 1A EA",
  "session id"          : "DD 61 0A ED B9 2D 52 DA EB 5C DF 1C 61 B3 73 49 9C 7C A4 CF C5 E2 1D 00 F5 24 B2 DB 5B 58 B0 94",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0x1303), TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=endpoint.server
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_ps
s_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_ps
s_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1]
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.3]
    },
    "psk_key_exchange_modes (45)": {
      "ke_modes": [psk_dhe_ke]
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "client_shares": [
        {
          "named group": secp256r1
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: 04 ac 3a de da 54 45 3a  48 e2 95 d9 97 24 bd 38  .....TE.H......8
            0010: cf bb e3 8c b9 98 e6 31  46 06 da 89 db 07 2e c7  .......1F.......
            0020: 77 79 8d bc 39 8b 54 f8  a1 ab 27 1f 39 b2 6e aa  wy..9.T.....9.n.
            0030: be ae 5d 50 c1 19 69 4a  9f 60 20 1a 61 40 ba ce  ...P..iJ....a...
            0040: cf
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but, seems like it wants to use the following ciphers:

```
[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0x1303), TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301)]
```

And those ciphers are for TLSv1.3, but according to the following, it is using TLSv1.2.

```
"client version"      : "TLSv1.2"
```

The server that I'm trying to connect to "endpoint.server" is supporting only TLSv1.2 and the following ciphers:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA265
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA265
```

For what I have found it can't be the limited/unlimited security policy files, because they aren't changed between and according to this url: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdk-java-technology/8?topic=guide-sdk-security-policy-files#sdkpolicyfiles

I also tried this setting: com.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultCSName with the value true and false, but that didn't do anything.
And in the java.security it is using the following settings:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms = [MD2, MD5, SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer, RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224]
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms = [SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, DESede, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, DES_CBC]
```

As you can see, nothing here about that I disable TLSv1.2.

I also tried the following and that was that I copied the complete folder of: java/jre/lib/security of version 8.0.6.15 to 8.0.6.25.
And when I do a test connection after this it works.

Does anyone know what the difference is in the java/jre/lib/security between both version?
For what I know what I earlier said, the limited/unlimited security policy files are not changed according to the given url.

Comment: *"And those ciphers are for TLSv1.3, but according to the following, it is using TLSv1.2."* - TLS 1.3 is not announced as `client version` but inside `supported_versions`

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, then I miss understood that, at `client version` is says `TLSv1.2` but at the `supported_versions` is see it says version `TLSv1.3` am I correct?   And does that mean that I'm using `TLSv1.3` and those ciphers for `TLSv1.3` to the server that is using `TLSv1.2` and supporting only `TLSv1.2` ciphers?
Because if that is the case, I'm still confused why I'm trying to use TLSv1.3 and those ciphers, because for what I know I didn't enable TLSv1.3, but default it is disabled. [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdk-java-technology/8?topic=customization-enabling-tls-13)

Comment: Correct, the client is only supporting TLS 1.3 - both shown in the supported_versions and in the supported ciphers.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Ok, now I'm only confused about the reason why it's using TLSv1.3 and those ciphers, because by default TLSv1.3 is disabled if I'm correct according to this [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdk-java-technology/8?topic=customization-enabling-tls-13)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue, by editing the java.security file with Java 8.0.6.25 it looks like:

```
security.provider.1=com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2
security.provider.2=com.ibm.crypto.provider.IBMJCE
security.provider.3=com.ibm.crypto.plus.provider.IBMJCEPlus
security.provider.4=com.ibm.security.jgss.IBMJGSSProvider
security.provider.5=com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPath
security.provider.6=com.ibm.security.sasl.IBMSASL
security.provider.7=com.ibm.xml.crypto.IBMXMLCryptoProvider
security.provider.8=com.ibm.xml.enc.IBMXMLEncProvider
security.provider.9=com.ibm.security.jgss.mech.spnego.IBMSPNEGO
security.provider.10=sun.security.provider.Sun
```

I have changed it to:

```
security.provider.1=com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2
security.provider.2=com.ibm.crypto.provider.IBMJCE
security.provider.3=com.ibm.security.jgss.IBMJGSSProvider
security.provider.4=com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPath
security.provider.5=com.ibm.security.sasl.IBMSASL
security.provider.6=com.ibm.xml.crypto.IBMXMLCryptoProvider
security.provider.7=com.ibm.xml.enc.IBMXMLEncProvider
security.provider.8=com.ibm.security.jgss.mech.spnego.IBMSPNEGO
security.provider.9=sun.security.provider.Sun
```

For some reason it want to use com.ibm.crypto.plus.provider.IBMJCEPlus and even when this failed it wouldn't try an other one, so the most easiest whay was by removing com.ibm.crypto.plus.provider.IBMJCEPlus out of the java.security file.